# Use unset() to save memory

Tags: php, memory-management, unset

**Background**: I need to parse some large XML files line by line and save the infos in associative arrays. I'm parsing it with `DOMDocument`.

Even the memory saving not being an essential requirement, I'm trying to use the `unset()` to save some memory during my script execution to avoid any possible error of this type without use `ini_set` approaches and things like this.

See the code below to see my approach to do this:

```
        //using DOMDocument to get the tag product
        $countriesCovered = array();
        $countriesCoveredTag = $productTag->getElementsByTagName('countriesCovered')->item(0);
        $countries = $countriesCoveredTag->getElementsByTagName('country');
        foreach ($countries as $countryTag) {
            $country = array();
            $country['name'] = $countryTag->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $country['code'] = $countryTag->getElementsByTagName('code')->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $countriesCovered[] = $country;
            unset ($country);
        }
```

To me, it's logical that I'm saving memory doing this, since I'm copying the variable `country` to the array `countriesCovered` and unset `country` (I mean freeing memory that was allocated to `country`, right?). However, I didn't found anything to ensure this in the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php), so I can't ensure that I'm really saving memory.

Thus,
Am I doing this in the right way? 
Is it needed even with the [Garbage Collection](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php)? I think that perhaps the `unset` might be totally worthless, but I can't ensure this.

Comment: You can check memory consumption with `memory_get_usage()` and `memory_get_peak_usage()`. The `unset` in this case doesn't do very much, you're still keeping a reference to the `$country` variable in `$countriesCovered`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without temporary variable

```
$countriesCovered[] = [
    'name' => $countryTag->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'code' => $countryTag->getElementsByTagName('code')->item(0)->nodeValue
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not entirely true. PHP does not have any biuld-in memory management mechanism. It entirely relies on garbage collection, so to truly free any memory, you need to call garbage collection process. Unset actually only decrements internal reference counter and does nothing with the memory itself. Once reference counter reaches zero, the garbage collector will free the memory.

You may want to check how garbage collector may affect application performance in composer's case study. Check out [how one line change caused composer to run 70% faster](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2o1nuk/one_php_line_changed_and_composer_run_70_faster/)

For your case unset will actually do nothing. **PHP internally does not copy variable immediatelly after assignment**. It creates a reference instead and incerements internal reference counter. The variable is really copied only when it is modified after assignment. **So your $country variable is pointing to the same memory address as the item in $countriesCovered array**.

Answer (score 1):

As Alexander Madyuskin said, you do not need to declare the variable inside the loop; you can just set the variables directly into your main associative array. Regardless, you won't be loosing much memory anyway since you are only really creating a couple of references (not multiple values).

Even if you were manipulating the value, which would result in multiple copies of the **value** (as opposed to multiple references) being made, the local variable falls out of scope at the end of each iteration anyway; so calling unset is unnecessary.

**Garbage Collection in General**

The broader point that you are asking about concerning garbage collection is this:

> The garbage collector will free up memory on its own when variables
>   fall out of scope

A variable is deemed to have fallen out of scope when there are no accessible references to it; so variables defined in `foreach` loops or `if` conditions are eligible for collection at the end of the iteration or conditional.

**Example:**

```
$externalArr = [];
while ($x=0; $x<50; $x++) {
  $internalArr = []
  $externalArr[] = $x;
  $internalArr[] = $x;

  // End of loop, $internalArr is now eligible for 
  // garbage collection regardless of whether it is unset
}

// The $externalArr is still in scope, so if we want it to be 
// collected, we have to manually unset it, or else it will exist 
// until the end of the script execution
unset($externalArr);
```